# How can i create my custom login with google MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, google-signin

I want to create my custom login with google using MVC i don't want to use OAuth and identity. Is there any way to create own custom login with google.

Comment: You need to use OAuth  or you can rewrite the OAuth framework your self :-)

Comment: How can i rewrite OAuth ? Please provide me help

Comment: :-) well you need to write a framework to authenticate your users and application using google API.  that is what oAuth does

Comment: Can you please provide me example

Comment: mate, this is not a simple example. but you can start from here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/  ( use Google to search please)

Comment: I have got a solution from your given link